# Скрытие элемента в контейнере при уменьшение экрана flex

Tags: html, css

В примере сейчас 4 элемента. Задача в том что могут добавляться новые элементы, их может быть любое количество, это блок акции на сайте. Сейчас в медиа запросах указаны конкретные элементы которые должны скрываться, а нужно сделать так чтобы они скрывались автоматом вне зависимости от того сколько будет элементов в контейнере. Чтобы после добавления нового не приходилось переписывать стили, уйти от привязки к определённому элементу.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="example"></div>
  <div class="example"></div>
  <div class="example"></div>
  <div class="example"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.example {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 200px;
  width: 20%;
}

@media (max-width: 1350px) {
    .example:last-child {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 1050px) {
    .example:nth-child(3) {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
    .example:nth-child(2) {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я понял, вам нужно чтобы для разных экранов показывалось только определенное количество элементов (первых по списку). Для этого можно использовать:

```
.example:nth-child(n+2) {
    display: none;
}
```

В данном случае все элементы ниже второго будут спрятаны
Или:

```
.example:nth-child(n+3) {
    display: none;
}
```

В данном случае все элементы ниже третьего будут спрятаны. Поставьте эти стили для нужного медиазапроса и все.